# Adding a page loader using jQuery

Tags: jquery, pageload, page-loading-message

I need a little help. I do not know where to start. I need to add a page loader to my website. I first submit a form it then uses SimpleXML to call an exterior XML Sheet with expedia... It takes a minute to load, so I would like to add the image loader to this page. But how do I go about doing this? I have looked on Google and could not find any useful info.

I need it to show the loader until the COMPLETE page has loaded.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has many solutions, but a simple one is to:

1- Create an overlay DIV with your loader stuff and prepend to BODY;
2- Add an event listener for `window.load` or `document.ready` event that hides this DIV.

```
// On the first line inside BODY tag
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("body").prepend('<div id="preloader">Loading...</div>');
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#preloader").remove();
    });
</script>
```

*(code typos fixed)*

Comment: Note: `window.load` fires first and then `document.ready` after the content finishes loading.

Comment: **Correcting:** `document.ready` fires when all HTML has fineshed loading, but before the content, and `window.load` fires after the content finishes loading

Answer (score 4):

Check out spin.js http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/

```
var opts = {
lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
length: 7, // The length of each line
width: 4, // The line thickness
radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
// Even more options available.... 
};
var target = document.getElementById('loading');
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
```

And once your form is done:

```
$("#loading").data('spinner').stop();
```

Answer (score 2):

This loader div will show a loading image on page load.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".pageloader").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;/* for this demo */
}

.pageloader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url('images/yourLoaderImage.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249, 249, 249);
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pageloader"></div>
```

It's Completely working for me.

Comment: For jquery versions >3,  .load(), .unload(), and .error() removed, 
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on("load", function (e) {
            $(".pageloader").fadeOut("slow");
        });
        </script>

Comment: Thanks @mightyteja for providing details for updated Jquery version.

Comment: This is not working if I open link in a new tab and visit that tab after sometime. If you have any solution please let me know.