# How to set a minimal duration for my page loader in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to set up a page loader for my website. Every time a user loads another page it will show the page loader until the page is done loading.

But for most of the cases, the web load so fast, and the page loader isn't shown. I tried to use `setTimeout` for 5 seconds but it make the loader show endlessly.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeOut(()=> {
$('.loader').remove();
} , 5000); // after 5 sec it will remove.
});
```

```css
/*Loading Screen*/
.loader {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
display: block;
opacity: 0.8;
background-color:#221e1e;
z-index: 99;
text-align: center;
}

.loader img {
-webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 45%;
z-index: 100;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
  }
  
  @keyframes spin {
0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader">
  <img src="img/logo/logo1.png" width="200px" height="75px">
</div>
```

Comment: First time I see someone complaining that their pages load too fast...

Comment: Its `setTimeout` not `setTimeOut`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**javascript** is **Case Sensitive** language

So it is sensitive to the letters **uppercase** and **uppercase**

The letter `o` is a large `setTimeOut` function that must be small, ie: `setTimeout`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(()=> {
        $('.loader').remove();
    } , 5000); // after 5 sec it will remove.
});
```

```css
/*Loading Screen*/
.loader {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
display: block;
opacity: 0.8;
background-color:#221e1e;
z-index: 99;
text-align: center;
}

.loader img {
-webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 45%;
z-index: 100;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
  }
  
  @keyframes spin {
0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader">
  <img src="img/logo/logo1.png" width="200px" height="75px">
</div>
```

**It is also good to know these things:**

The loader is usually installed when the screen is not fully loaded

```
$(document).ready(function () {

}
```

`ready()` Runs when the page is fully loaded
You can write your loader outside of this function

Please read the following links:

https://api.jquery.com/ready/

[Adding a page loader using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365523/adding-a-page-loader-using-jquery)

[How to do jquery code AFTER page loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926227/how-to-do-jquery-code-after-page-loading)

**Description**: Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

You can also use the following plugin for the loader

https://plugins.jquery.com/loader/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, so should I just add the timer on my css ? is it better ?

Comment: You do not need a timer for the loader
In jquery, the ready() function is executed whenever the page is fully loaded
So by running this function you are sure that the page is fully loaded and you can delete your loader in that function

Comment: oh I see, but my client want to at least show loader for about 2-3 seconds even though the page is fully loaded, can u help me to do that ? Thanks before

Comment: No problem, you can remove the loader a few seconds later

Comment: how can I do that? by adding duration through the css ? sorry for asking so much. I'm new

Comment: I put the correct code in the answer, see it

Comment: Oh finally it works, Thankyou all for the help. Cheers